# User-created VBA function returns #VALUE

Tags: vba, function, excel

I am in the early stages of creating a vba function that will extract the email address from a cell, and then do a vlookup for a unique ID.

The cells on which I'll be using the function say things like this:

"This message was sent to email@email.com by SOB on July 31st"
or
"Message sent to email@email.com by SOB 7/31"

The first thing I want to do is erase anything that comes after the email address. To do this, the function will search for "by SOB on July 31st" OR "by SOB 7/31" and replace it with nothing.

I wrote the following code to try to accomplish this, but I am getting an error message when I use it in the workbook:

```
Function ExtractEmail(extractStr As String) As String

Dim DateText As String
Dim DateNum As String

DateText = "by SOB on July 31st"
DateNum = "by SOB 7/31"

If InStr(extractStr, DateText ) Then
    Left(extractStr, InStr(extractStr, DateText )) = extractStr
        ElseIf InStr(extractStr, DateNum ) Then
            Left(extractStr, InStr(extractStr, DateNum )) = extractStr
        Else
            extractStr = "Nothing Found"

End If




End Function
```

So this:

> This message was sent to email@email.com by SOB on July 31st

should return:

> This message was sent to email@email.com

Any idea why I'm getting the error #Value!?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're assigning your values the wrong way around and your function doesn't return anything. `extractStr` isn't the same as `ExtractEmail`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning things the wrong way around, and you need to actually return a value from the function using the name of the UDF. I think this is what you're after:

```
Function ExtractEmail(extractStr As String) As String

Dim DateText As String
Dim DateNum As String

DateText = "by SOB on July 31st"
DateNum = "by SOB 7/31"

If InStr(extractStr, DateText ) Then
    extractStr = Left(extractStr, InStr(extractStr, DateText ))
ElseIf InStr(extractStr, DateNum ) Then
    extractStr = Left(extractStr, InStr(extractStr, DateNum ))
Else
    extractStr = "Nothing Found"
End If

ExtractEmail = extractStr

End Function
```

Comment: Also don't forget you are returning the position of the first character returned by the InStr function - so giving the Left up to that gives "Message sent to email@email.com b" - put a -1 on your left string (or -2 if you want to remove the space too!)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove anything after " by SOB " then:

```
Function ExtractEmail(extractStr As String) As String

    ExtractEmail = Split(extractStr, " by SOB ")(0)

End Function
```